# Merge two arrays of objects and add array name as a property

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I try to merge two arrays of objects and at the same time add their name as a property to the objects:

```
const firstGroup = [
    {
        firstname: 'Nick',
        id: 1
    },
    {
        firstname: 'Joe',
        id: 2
    },
]

const secondGroup = [
    {
        firstname: 'Tom',
        id: 1
    },
]
```

The desired output:

```
allGroups = [
    {
        groupname: 'firstGroup',
        firstname: 'Nick',
        id: 1
    },
    {
        groupname: 'firstGroup',
        firstname: 'Joe',
        id: 2
    },
    {
        groupname: 'secondGroup',
        firstname: 'Tom',
        id: 1
    }
]
```

Here is what I tried:

```
Object
    .entries({ firstGroup, secondGroup })
    .reduce((acc, [name, [firstname, id]]) => ([{
        ...acc,
        groupname: name,
        firstname,
        id
    }]), [])
```

But it doesn't work and I can't figure out how I can do it.

Thanks for your help !

Comment: You'll have to pass the group names in explicitly, as the names of the source variables are not available in the function.

Comment: @Pointy - The OP had a clever solution to that: shorthand property notation creating an object. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder ah ok I see that now, well that's well and good but it still essentially hard-codes the "group" names, which is fine by me of course.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code was close, but you're creating a new array on each iteration rather than modifying the "accumulator" array `reduce` passes around, and only taking the properties from the first entry in the source array, not all of them.

`reduce` just adds complexity here IMHO, I'd use a `for-of` loop over the entries of the object you created. Within the loop body, map the entries to new entries with the group name, then push them all on `allGroups`. Like this:

```
const allGroups = [];
for (const [groupname, entries] of Object.entries({firstGroup, secondGroup})) {
    allGroups.push(...entries.map(entry => ({groupname, ...entry})));
}
```

Live Example:

```js
const firstGroup = [
    {
        firstname: 'Nick',
        id: 1
    },
    {
        firstname: 'Joe',
        id: 2
    },
];

const secondGroup = [
    {
        firstname: 'Tom',
        id: 1
    },
];

const allGroups = [];
for (const [groupname, entries] of Object.entries({firstGroup, secondGroup})) {
    allGroups.push(...entries.map(entry => ({groupname, ...entry})));
}
console.log(allGroups);
```

But here's a working version of your `reduce` approach:

```js
const firstGroup = [
    {
        firstname: 'Nick',
        id: 1
    },
    {
        firstname: 'Joe',
        id: 2
    },
];

const secondGroup = [
    {
        firstname: 'Tom',
        id: 1
    },
];

const allGroups = Object.entries({ firstGroup, secondGroup })
    .reduce((acc, [groupname, entries]) => {
        acc.push(...entries.map(entry => ({groupname, ...entry})));
        return acc;
    }, []);
console.log(allGroups);
```

---

In a comment you've asked:

> ...what if I want in the final object just a selection of the initial properties eg. `groupname`, `firstname` but not `id` ?

You'd change the places above where I have `entry =>` to `({firstname}) =>` to destructure the listed property(ies) from the object, and change where I have `...entry` to `firstname` to fill in just that/those properties on the new object. So for instance:

```
allGroups.push(...entries.map(({firstname}) => ({groupname, firstname})));
```

Live example - `for-of`:

```js
const firstGroup = [
    {
        firstname: 'Nick',
        id: 1
    },
    {
        firstname: 'Joe',
        id: 2
    },
];

const secondGroup = [
    {
        firstname: 'Tom',
        id: 1
    },
];

const allGroups = [];
for (const [groupname, entries] of Object.entries({firstGroup, secondGroup})) {
    allGroups.push(...entries.map(({firstname}) => ({groupname, firstname})));
}
console.log(allGroups);
```

Live example - `reduce`:

```js
const firstGroup = [
    {
        firstname: 'Nick',
        id: 1
    },
    {
        firstname: 'Joe',
        id: 2
    },
];

const secondGroup = [
    {
        firstname: 'Tom',
        id: 1
    },
];

const allGroups = Object.entries({ firstGroup, secondGroup })
    .reduce((acc, [groupname, entries]) => {
        acc.push(...entries.map(({firstname}) => ({groupname, firstname})));
        return acc;
    }, []);
console.log(allGroups);
```

Comment: The `for ... of` loop is fine. But what if I want in the final object just a selection of the initial properties eg. `groupname`, `firstname` but not `id` ?

Comment: @Tom - I've updated the answer to show how to do that.

Comment: I missed the brackets when destructuring `firstname`. Sorry I can't vote twice... Thanks a lot

Comment: @Tom - Happy to help! I **really** go back and forth on the question of whether to leave out the optional `()` around an arrow function's parameter list if there's just one non-destructured parameter. If I'd included them here, you wouldn't have run into trouble. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Below snippet of code can be used to achieve the result.

```
Object.entries({ firstGroup, secondGroup }).reduce((acc, [groupname, groupItems]) => {

for (item of groupItems){

    acc.push({
    ...item,
    groupname
    });
}

return acc; 

}, [])
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to it, you can use [`flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) or [`flat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) to avoid using `reduce` entirely.

Passing an array to `reduce` and pushing an item onto the accumulator per element is an antipattern because [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) does this specific operation (applying a callback to every item in an array) with cleaner syntax and semantics. The only reason `reduce` was chosen is because a flattening operation is needed, but `flatMap` expresses this intent more clearly.

```js
const firstGroup = [{firstname: 'Nick', id: 1}, {firstname: 'Joe', id: 2}]; 
const secondGroup = [{firstname: 'Tom', id: 1}];

const result = Object.entries({firstGroup, secondGroup})
  .flatMap(([groupname, arr]) => arr.map(({id, firstname}) => ({
    groupname, firstname, id
  })))
;
console.log(result)
```

Using `flat`:

```js
const firstGroup = [{firstname: 'Nick', id: 1}, {firstname: 'Joe', id: 2}]; 
const secondGroup = [{firstname: 'Tom', id: 1}];

const result = Object.entries({firstGroup, secondGroup})
  .map(([groupname, arr]) => arr.map(({id, firstname}) => ({
    groupname, firstname, id
  })))
  .flat()
;
console.log(result)
```

If you don't have access to either, there's [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)/[`concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat):

```js
const firstGroup = [{firstname: 'Nick', id: 1}, {firstname: 'Joe', id: 2}]; 
const secondGroup = [{firstname: 'Tom', id: 1}];

const result = [].concat(...Object.entries({firstGroup, secondGroup})
  .map(([groupname, arr]) => arr.map(({id, firstname}) => ({
    groupname, firstname, id
  }))))
;
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score -1):

No need to over complicate things, this will work just fine:

```
const firstGroup = [
    {
        firstname: 'Nick',
        id: 1
    },
    {
        firstname: 'Joe',
        id: 2
    },
]

const secondGroup = [
    {
        firstname: 'Tom',
        id: 1
    },
]

firstGroup.map(x => x.groupname = 'firstGroup');
secondGroup.map(x => x.groupname = 'secondGroup');

const allGroups = [].concat(firstGroup, secondGroup);
console.log(allGroups);
```

Comment: You definitely do not, that example runs just fine.

Comment: If you're not using the return value of `map` (the array it creates), `map` isn't the right tool. For the above, you'd want `forEach`, `for-of`, or a simple `for` loop. Other than that, yeah, if it's okay to modify the existing objects, this is nice and simple and gets the job done.

Comment: I disagree, the map function is perfect for this as I'm altering the structure of the object in those arrays.

Comment: @nerdybeast you can do that in a `.forEach()` loop too. There's no need for `.map()`.

Comment: @nerdybeast It works, but since you're using map, it will return a new array. Since you're not making use of that array, you might as well use forEach instead - it'll  have the same output

Comment: That has nothing to do with what `map` does. You're using it as a general iterator. That's not what it's for. It's for building a **new** array. (But wow, I *would not* downvote this answer on that basis!)